# Selenium: can't click "next page" in search results

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click the "next" button on the results page of bing.com. I've tried three ways and cant seem to get it to work. I've tried:

```
next_page = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sb_pagN sb_pagN_bp b_widePag sb_bp ')
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Next page']")
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@h='ID=SERP,5502.1']")

next_page.click()
```

Comment: What website is this from and html element are you grabbing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.get("https://bing.com")
send = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sb_form_q")))
send.send_keys("Town")
send.submit()
```

A more dynamic way to always find the next element by css_selector.

```
next_page=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#b_results > li.b_pag > nav > ul > li:last-child")))
next_page.click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```